# El proyecto a veces no me reconoce una clase

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo una clase que uso para generar los botones personalizados de mi proyecto en winforms , simplemente defino la fuente..color y de esta forma uso este botón personalizado en todos mis formularios.

La estructura de archivos y directorios que tengo es esta , dentro de la solución tengo esta clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Contenido de la clase controlesPersonalizado**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace controlesPersonalizado
{
    public class botonColor : Button
    {
        private static event EventHandler ColorCambiado;
        private static Color fondo = Color.White;
        private static Color colorfuente = Color.Black;

        public static Color Fondo
        {
            get
            {
                return fondo;
            }
            set
            {
                fondo = value;
                if (ColorCambiado != null) ColorCambiado(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public static Color ColorFuente
        {
            get
            {
                return colorfuente;
            }
            set
            {
                colorfuente = value;
                if (ColorCambiado != null) ColorCambiado(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public botonColor()
        {
            Fondo = fondo;
            ColorFuente = colorfuente;

            this.BackColor = fondo;
            this.ForeColor = colorfuente;
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

            ColorCambiado += botonColor_ColorCambiado;
        }


        private void botonColor_ColorCambiado(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = fondo;
            this.ForeColor = colorfuente;
        }
    }

}
```

El problema que tengo es que a veces (no siempre) cuando abro el formulario en modo diseño me aparece este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo unas capturas de las propiedades del archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A veces recompilando toda la solución , cerrando el formulario y volviendolo a abrir funciona pero otra veces no.
Que puedo hacer?

Gracias,

Answer (score 3):

Esto se debe a que copiaste directamente el archivo a la carpeta y lo que hace Visual Studio es reconocer ese archivo pero no como parte del proyecto, para solucionarlo debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Clic derecho al archivo
2. Incliur en el proyecto

Una vez realizado esto, Visual Studio lo reconocerá como parte del proyecto y no te enviará errores.

Comment: mas que esto, no es que esta buscando el archivo compilado, y no lo encuentra (asi sea pq cambio o pq se borro)? no me suena que no este en el proyecto.. si es un boton personalizado debe estar compilado...

Comment: @gbianchi hice un ejercicio rápido y justo acabo de replicar el escenario, pasa justamente lo que comento al principio de mi respuesta, aunque es posible que el problema también se dé por otras circunstancias que desconozco.

Comment: @Flxtr en botón derecho solo me sale la opción de "excluir del proyecto" por lo que entiendo que esta correctamente en el proyecto

Answer (score 1):

Deberías verificar el namespace de la clase e importarlo correctamente. muchas veces borrandolo y dándole add -> existing Item (fuera de que lo agrega al proyecto) corrige el namespace (igualmente validarlo)